# how to use nuxt module in an external script?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, nuxt.js

I am creating a website using `nuxt`. 
I create a directory called services and some scripts are in it. I want to use the [@nuxt/device](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/device) module in a script. The usage of the module is this way `this.$device.isDesktop`. But in an external script I do not have access to `nuxt` instance like `this`.

The structure of my project is like this:

[image]

And i want to use this package in `search_report.js` file. Content of `search_report.js` is like this:

```
import Api from '~/services/api';

export default class SearchReport{

    static instance = undefined;

    search_query_id = undefined;

    static get_instance(){
        if(SearchReport.instance === undefined){
            SearchReport.instance = new SearchReport();
        }
        return SearchReport.instance;
    }

    log_search_query(query, success_callback, error_callback){
        let self = this;
        Api.send_ajax_get('http://example.com/add_search_query/' + query + '/', data, function(result) {
                self.search_query_id = result.data.search_query_id;
                if(success_callback){
                    success_callback();
                }
            },error_callback);
    }
}
```

I want to use this package in `log_search_query` method to send device type to the server.

How can I use a `nuxt-module` in an external script?

Comment: where do u want to use in external

Comment: nope you can't there is no option right now however you can use this logic to your layout as mounted